# React Native is not compiling new changes

Tags: react-native

I'm making some changes on my app (I have to say I just started on this old app) but it never takes the changes.

The easiest change I can make is update the image for the splashscreen like this:

```
export const SplashScreen = (props: any) => (
  <View style={[styles.container, { width: width, height: height }]}>
    <Image
      style={styles.background}
      source={require("https://imgcomfort.com/Userfiles/Upload/images/illustration-geiranger.jpg")}
    />
  </View>
);
```

Also I changed the `index` to a default one to remove any extra dependencies.

When I run `npm start` I get this error:

> Error: Compilation of µWebSockets has failed and there is no
>   pre-compiled binary available for your system. Please install a
>   supported C++11 compiler and reinstall the module 'uws'.

And when I run `react-native run-android` I still having the previous image for the splashscreen. After showing this it closes automaticall (so it also doesn't pick the changes in `index.tsx`).

I tried also removing `android` and `ios` folders and running `react-native eject` but I got some different issues and I don't really want to update the whole thing.
Similar scenario if I update some packages. I'd prefer to run the app as it is.

My Android Studio is also updated to latest changes.

I cannot see any `build` folder after running the app and I'm using these versions:

```
"react": "~15.4.0",
"react-native": "0.41.2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
"uws": "^10.148.0"
```

This happens in Windows and Linux (with different Android Studio obviously)

Comment: Have you looked into the error message?  Seems to me that the error is preventing compiling a new version of the app, and that's why you see the old version.

Comment: Ok, I thought this was more Android or Node/npm related. I installed this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/ It was suggested on a different question here. I couldn't find any relation with this and React Native tho.
After installing this I try running again `react-native start --reset-cache` and still getting same error.

Comment: Also as I said I removed completely the code I had on that `index` so if I had any connexion with any server or any extra function which depends on a 3rd party library I'm not using it, just the `index` created when you do `react-native init demo` so it shouldn't display any issue with anything... I guess. Could be something related to cache or anything like that? Android folder is the same, it could related to that maybe?

Comment: When you remove the code that you had on index, do you still see the error about WebSockets failing?

Comment: yeah, the same. That error is always there when I run `npm start`

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then reinstalling uws?

Comment: yes (and btw it changed from version 10.148 to version 100.0), but didn't help